# Finding the maximum value between a given interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table like so, where the amount is some arbitrary amount of something(like fruit or something but we don't care about the type)

```
row  |  amount
_______________

1    |  54
2    |  2
3    |  102
4    |  102
5    |  1
```

And I want to select the rows that have the maximum value within a given interval.  For instance if I was only wanting to select from rows 2-5 what would be returned would be

```
row  |  amount
_______________

3    |  102
4    |  102
```

Because they both contain the max value within the interval, which is 102.  Or if I chose to only look at rows 1-2 it would return

```
row  |  amount
_______________

1    |  54
```

Because the maximum value in the interval 1-2 only exists in row 1

I tried to use a variety of:

```
amount= (select MAX(amount) FROM arbitraryTable)
```

But that will only ever return

```
row  |  amount
_______________

3    |  102
4    |  102
```

Because 102 is the absolute max of the table.  Can you find the maximum value between a given interval?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `rank()` or `max()` as a window function:

```
select t.row, t.amount
from (select t.*, max(amount) over () as maxamount
      from t
      where row between 2 and 4
     ) t
where amount = maxamount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the max value and use it in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    row,
    amount
FROM
    arbitraryTable
WHERE
    row BETWEEN 2 AND 5 AND
    amount = (
        SELECT
            MAX(amount)
        FROM
            arbitraryTable
        WHERE
            row BETWEEN 2 AND 5
    );
```

Just remember to use the same conditions in the main and sub query: `row BETWEEN 2 AND 5`.